# Event on checkboxes not happening

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a series of checkboxes and I am running the following but it never happens and the console gives no result

```
jQuery( ".masonry input[checkbox]" ).on("change", function() {
  if(jQuery(this).is(":checked")) {
    console.log("changed");
    jQuery('#terzo').removeAttr("disabled");
  }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="masonry">
    <div class="item">
        <input type="checkbox" name="thing_1" value="valuable" id="thing_1">
            <label for="thing_1">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://independentskies.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/428126-3732x2655.jpg">
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
                <input type="checkbox" name="thing_2" value="valuable" id="thing_2">
            <label for="thing_2">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://viajescasaquinta.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Grecia.jpg">
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Show your HTML. Is the code in `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: @Barmar there you go, quetsion updated with html if ever was needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"input[checkbox]"` is not a valid `css` selector to select `<input type="checkbox">` element. Use `"input[type=checkbox]"`

Comment: Or the jQuery abbreviation `:checkbox`

Comment: Note also, double quotes surrounding attribute value are required at `css` `input[type="checkbox"]`

Comment: I don't think they are, unless the type contains space or other special characters.

Comment: just tried     `jQuery( '.masonry input[type="checkbox"]' ).on("change", function() {
      if(jQuery(this).is(":checked")) {
        console.log("changed");
        jQuery('#terzo').removeAttr("disabled");
      }
    });` and i got no console neither

Comment: I just typed `$("input[type=text]")` in the console and it worked.

Comment: @Barmar At `css`, that is, `stylesheet` or `.textContent` of `<style>` element

Comment: @Barmar since I am on jquery could you elaborate you comment base don my code while using `:checkbox`

Comment: By the way, when you deal with properties and not attributes, I would recommend you to use `prop`: [http://api.jquery.com/prop/](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Comment: @RobertoMarras Are the elements appended to `document` dynamically?

Comment: @guest271314 yes they are actually, via ajax

Comment: @guest271314 hmm ok i think i know what you mean, I will append this js too with the ajax and see how it goes

Comment: @RobertoMarras You can attach the event to the element when created using `jQuery(html, attributes)` [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements/43224244?s=2|0.0000#43224244) or use event delegation `$(document).on("change", '.masonry input[type="checkbox"]', function(){//do stuff})`

Comment: @guest271314 that's it, since I was using ajax and I actually had a click in there, i simply added  `jQuery('#terzo').removeAttr("disabled");` and it worked. Will accept your answer for future users as it is correct tho

Comment: @RobertoMarras _"that's it"_ Do you mean `"input[checkbox]"` selector referenced `<input type="checkbox">` element?

Comment: @guest271314 with _that's it_ i refer to your comment _Are the elements appended to document dynamically_ which made me realise I was actually calling these via ajax, so the code wouldn't work regardless. Regardless of the fact i was wrongly using the selector as you have correctly pointed out `"input[type=checkbox]"` instead of  `"input[checkbox]"` so your answer is correct

Comment: @Barmar You are correct. The quotes are required at `css` surrounding attribute value that is a number, see versions 1 and 2 at  http://plnkr.co/edit/QdeU1OeYIpyHmIis1fPX?p=preview, not at `[attrName=attrValueWithoutSpacesOrSpecialCharacters]` versions 3, 4.